# unable to send mail from contact form via php

Tags: php, jquery, contact-form

I'm trying to implement a contact form on my mobile app. I'm using a plugin called "Ffform", which can be found here http://www.egrappler.com/ffform-free-jquery-contact-form-plugin-with-validations-amazing-css3-animation/

To my unexperienced eyes everything looks looks ok. When i press the submit button i get the success prompt "your email has been sent". The problem is that the email never reaches my inbox. I've basically no idea where the problem lies. As I've mentioned, I'm pretty unexperienced and are still trying to wrap my head around this code.

Any help with identifying the problem would be greatly appreciated.

This is the form itself:

```
<div class="container">
<form class="contact" action="email.php" method="post" id="form">

<div class="row clearfix">
<div class="lbl">
<label for="name">Name</label>
</div>
<div class="ctrl">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" data-required="true" data-validation="text"
data-msg="Invalid Name" placeholder="Ex: John Donga">
</div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix">
<div class="lbl">
<label for="email">E-Mail</label>
</div>
<div class="ctrl">
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" data-required="true" data-validation="email"
data-msg="Invalid E-Mail" placeholder="Ex: youremail@domain.com">
</div>
</div>


<div class="row  clearfix">
<div class="span10 offset2">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Send Message">
</div>
</div>
</form>
<div id="success">
Your E-Mail has been sent successfully!</div>
<div id="error">
Unable to send e-mail at the moment, please try later.</div>
<div id="validation">
</div>
</div>
```

This are the contents of the php file. I've replaced "my_email@domain" with my own email.

```
<?php 

$send_email_to = "my_email@domain";
$email_subject = "hei";

$email = $_POST['email'];

$name = $_POST['name'];


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$email. "\r\n";

$message = "<strong>Email = </strong>".$email."<br>";
$message .= "<strong>Name = </strong>".$name."<br>";  

@mail($send_email_to, $email_subject, $message,$headers);

header('Content-type: text/json');
$return_array['success'] = '1';
echo json_encode($return_array);
die();
?>
```

I'll post the javascript aswell if needed

Comment: it's very hard to debug any thing when you hide the errors

Comment: try `mail` command without @ to see what exact errors come up

Comment: @Javad no errors showing

Comment: Are you testing it in your local machine? If yes, make sure SMTP is configured correctly and if you are sending internal mail you don't need password but for external you need password